# MySQL & PHP | Update doesnt work after select

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, sql-update

I have this weird situation where my query isn't doing what it's supposed to do.

Here is my not working code:

```
$aanbodID = 1;
$db = //connection

$getData = $db->query("SELECT boekbaar_iframe FROM aanbod_20160206 WHERE id_aanbod=$aanbodID") or die(mysql_error());
while ($row_content = mysql_fetch_array($getData)) 
{       
    $zichtbaarjanee = $row_content['boekbaar_iframe']; // 0 or 1
}

if ($zichtbaarjanee == 0)
{
    $nieuwewaarde = 1;
}else{
    $nieuwewaarde = 0;
}

db->query("UPDATE aanbod_20160206 SET boekbaar_iframe = '$nieuwewaarde' WHERE id_aanbod = '$aanbodID'");
echo mysql_error();
```

And here is almost the same code that is working:

```
 $aanbodID = 1;
$db = //connection

$getData = $db->query("SELECT boekbaar_iframe FROM aanbod_20160206 WHERE id_aanbod=$aanbodID") or die(mysql_error());
while ($row_content = mysql_fetch_array($getData)) 
{       
    $zichtbaarjanee = $row_content['boekbaar_iframe']; // 0 or 1
}

//switch these vars and its working    
$nieuwewaarde = 0;
// $nieuwewaarde = 1; 

db->query("UPDATE aanbod_20160206 SET boekbaar_iframe = '$nieuwewaarde' WHERE id_aanbod = '$aanbodID'");
echo mysql_error();
```

So i'm guessing the problem is somewhere in the if statement, but i've tried everything, also with and without ' ' or " ".

**update:** changed querys to mysqli_*

the problem is still in the if/else statement

because this is working:

```
//if ($zichtbaarjanee == 0)
//{
//  $nieuwewaarde = 1;
//}else{
    $nieuwewaarde = 0;
//}
```

When I switch the 0 for a 1 it's also working, but when i comment in the piece of code it stops updating the table

Please help!

Comment: and `mysql_error()` says what?

Comment: Please [don't use `mysql_*`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php?rq=1); the `mysql_*` functions are outdated, [deprecated](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php), and insecure. Use [`MySQLi`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: @Fred-ii- there is no error. Acording to the code everything should work.

Comment: can we see `tbl` table DDL definition?

Comment: what about error reporting; is that set? If not... http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: also, try putting your `if ($zichtbaarjanee == 0)` inside the `while` loop.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes, on E_ALL

Comment: Maybe I am being a little simplistic here BUT your UPDATE statement is in a `db->query()` Should that not be `$db->query()` i.e. You did not put a `$` infront of the `db` variable name

Answer (score 0):

Every instance of MySQL needs to be replaced with MySQL**i**
As it was deprecated in PHP 5.5.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

And trying to concatenate:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE aanbod_20160206 SET boekbaar_iframe = ".$nieuwewaarde." WHERE id_aanbod = ".$aanbodID."");
```

Should be changed to:

```
mysqli_query("UPDATE aanbod_20160206 SET boekbaar_iframe = '$nieuwewaarde' WHERE id_aanbod = '$aanbodID'");
```

I understand you're trying to embed the variable in the query, however in this case it would just add 2 dots on either side of your variable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it isn't working. As i said, the problem is in the if-statement not in the query.

Comment: Update your original code with the new and improved version, gives me and others a better idea of what could be wrong.